# Create SQL Table and Populate it

Tags: php, sql

I have a script that creates a SQL table for me as below

```
 if ($con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
    if (mysql_select_db($db_name)) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$ac_system."_credits (id INT NOT NULL   
 AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (id) , account_nr CHAR(10) , credits CHAR(10))";    
if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
```

I would like to add another line/s to populate the above table with fixed information

ID - 1
Credits - 10
ACCOUNT_NR - 1

The above data is constant and doesn't need to be changed once the table is created I am not sure how to populate it in conjunction with the creation of the table. I can populate it from a seperate PHP script but need all to be done on one page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should execute another one query just after successful table creation:

```
 //some php code here
    $insertSuccessful = true;
    mysql_query( "INSERT INTO $ac_system ( account_nr, credits ) VALUES ( '1', '10' )", $sql );
// and here
```